# Alex is by Jan or Alex is with Jan

Tags: prepositions

First:

> Alex is by Jan.

or

> Alex is with Jan.

Second:

> Where's the ketchup? It's over there, by the mustard.

or

> Where's the ketchup? It's over there, with the mustard.

Answer (score 1):

"By" here means next to; "with" means accompanying by arrangement.  Alexis could be by Jan even if they're both strangers.  That unlikely if the two are with each other.

The difference in the two locutions is slight for inanimate objects.

Comment: Using 'with' for inanimate objects suggests a container to me, e.g. 'the salt is with the pepper in the cruet' http://www.vanishederas.com/ekmps/shops/vanishederas/images/zz-vintage-retro-red-domino-polka-dot-cruet-set-salt-and-pepper-pots-with-plastic-stand-by-embee-products-c.1950s-sold-[2]-5299-p.jpg

Comment: My perception is that the use of 'by + personal name' meaning 'beside ...' is on the wane, probably because of the common 'support' reading ('Alex is standing by the blue boat' is unremarkable). Also, missing out the 'standing' from 'Alex is standing by Jan' in a standalone (!) sentence sounds rather unnatural.  I'd think 'Alex is [the one] [standing] next to Jan' far more common (though I seem to remember that COCA results imply the opposite, even after filtering out the 'support' readings. Perhaps this is a written/spoken word difference.)

Comment: Adding something deictic improves it drastically, though: “Alex is over there, by/with Jan”. In that case, the arrangement aspect of _with_ is also lessened—it just indicates that they somehow make up their own ‘group’ of some kind or other, even if they don’t know each other and just happened to get to talking. _By_, on the other hand, almost unequivocally states that the two are _not_ interacting with each other, even though they are in close physical proximity to one another.

Answer (score 1):

*"Alex is by Jan"* could mean: Alex is standing/sitting by Jan, Jan gave birth to Alex, Jan styled Alex, Jan made Alex from spare parts she found in the hospital dumpster.

*"Alex is with Jan"* could mean: Alex is standing/sitting with Jan, Alex is here escorting Jan, Alex is in a relationship with Jan.

(Context is crucial in such a simple statement.) Unfortunately, many prepositions can be interpreted several ways. It helps to use personification, hyperbole, and metaphors to clarify your meaning.

Native speakers may say things like:

"The ketchup is in the refrigerator, hiding behind the pickles."

"The tumor on Jan's arm is called 'Alex'."

"Jan has Alex caught in her web."